# RegEx to replace a class name in a CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have a css file in which a class name appears multiple times. Call it .foo
The same name also appears in the file as foo and #foo

I'm trying to create a JavaScript regular expression that can match the css class .foo but disregard the other variations foo and #foo.

So far I've tried the following variations without success:

```
css.replace(/.foo/g,"")

css.replace(/^.foo/g,"")

css.replace(/^.foo*/g,"")

css.replace(/\b.foo/g,"")

css.replace(/.foo\b/g,"")
```

Comment: `.` in regex means "any character". Escape it.

Comment: Go read the tutorial at www.regular-expressions.info.

Comment: I wonder what if we have some `.foo` word such as in an image URL in the CSS file? replacing like this is too dangerous.

Comment: So you should do like this `css.replace(/\.foo(?=[^{]*\{)/g,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` to get a literal dot.

`css.replace(/\.foo/g, "");`

Answer (score 5):

Escape a dot in your regular expression:

```
css.replace(/\.foo/g, '');
```

Otherwise it will match [*any non newline character*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dot) before `foo`.

If you care about matching only `.foo` and not `.foobar` you may add `\b` to the regex as [@Niet suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523454/regex-to-replace-a-class-name-in-a-css-file/23523482#comment36082996_23523482) in the comments: `/\.foo\b/g`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol たのむぞ。ZIG！！

Comment: +1 because you know what you doing. But consider adding `\b` at the end so you don't match a `.foobar` class.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: although this may **rarely** happen but it depends on the actual string `foo`, such as we have this in the CSS file `background:url(http://whatever.foo/someimage);` then we know what will happen.

Comment: @KingKing Well, I personally wouldn't do parsing of CSS document especially with regular expressions. Regarding the current case it definitely depends on the context.

Comment: @VisioN yes, at least the context here is the `.foo` is a class selector which should always have a `{` following it (at the end). That context is even not strict enough but it's better than a `\b`.